# Resembling table field as some alias in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

In codeigniter i am creating a general function for some data insertion

for it i am keeping some norms

say i have two tables one being dt_category and the other being dt_product

here's the dt_category struture

```
|-------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------------|
| category_id       | category_name       | category_slug      |  timestamp       |
|-------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------------|
```

and here's the dt_product structure

```
|-------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------------|
| product_id        |  product_name       |  product_slug      |  timestamp       |
|-------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------------|
```

as u can see, both the tables fields just change by the field-name prefix, i mean in dt_category its category_id

and in dt_product its product_id and so on

now while calling the function to insert category data i use this method

```
$category_name=$this->input->post('category_name');
               $insert_array=array('category_name'=>$category_name,
                                   'timestamp'=>time());
               $data['msg']=$this->erp_model->data_insert('dt_category',$insert_array);
```

and for product data
just this method

```
$product_name=$this->input->post('product_name');
               $insert_array=array('product_name'=>$product_name,
                                   'timestamp'=>time());
               $data['msg']=$this->erp_model->data_insert('dt_product',$insert_array);
```

the function that deals with the insertion is this one

```
function data_insert($table,$data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($table,$data);
        $timestamp=$data['timestamp'];
        $table_nm=explode('_',$table); //spliting the table name in format dt_table_name,
        $table_slug=$table_nm[1]."_"."slug";//if its dt_product table_nm[1]="product", 
                                            //if category,table_nm[1]="category"
                                            //thus $table_slug="product_slug" or "category_slug"
        $query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from($table)
                        ->where('timestamp', $timestamp)
                        ->get();
        foreach($query->result() as $r_q)
        {
            $id=$r_q->$table_nm[1].'_id';//i want $id value of product_id since $table_nm[1]="product"
            $name=$r_q->$table_nm[1].'_name';//i want $name value of product_name since $table_nm[1]="product"
        }
        echo $id."-".$name;


    }
```

in the aboce function based on the table_name
i want to fetch the value of field name

```
$id=$r_q->$table_nm[1].'_id'; should resemble $id=$r_q->product_id; if the table is dt_product
```

i know i am doing the wrong way, because ->product_id is a resultanat object while i am trying to expressing as a string,

is there a way of how i can achieve the thing,

i mean fetching the field name based on the table name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved my problem, and here's the answer

i was trying the concatenation at the time of retrieval, 
but now i did it first and then assigned  the field

```
$tab_id=$table_nm[1].'_id';
            $tab_name=$table_nm[1].'_name';
```

here's the resolved code

```
function data_insert($table,$data)
        {
            $this->db->insert($table,$data);
            $timestamp=$data['timestamp'];
            $table_nm=explode('_',$table);
            $table_slug=$table_nm[1]."_"."slug";
            echo $table_slug;
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->from($table)
                            ->where('timestamp', $timestamp)
                            ->get();
            $tab_id=$table_nm[1].'_id';
            $tab_name=$table_nm[1].'_name';
            foreach($query->result() as $r_q)
            {
                $id=$r_q->$tab_id;
                $name=$r_q->$tab_name;
            }
            echo $id."-".$name;


        }
```